# MySql query with reverse joins

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to build a query returning a list of contacts associated with a specific opportunity.

I have 3 tables: contacts, opportunities, and relationships (many to many)

**contacts**

```
id   name
---------
1   Davey Jones
2   Bob Hope
3   Tiger Woods
4   Hillary Clinton
```

**opportunities**

```
id    description
------------------
1     visit the locker
2     singing and dancing
3     playing golf
4     laughing and crying
```

**relationships**

```
id     firstid     firsttype      secondid     secondtype
---------------------------------------------------------
1      1           contact        1           opportunity
2      3           opportunity    3           contact
3      4           contact        4           opportunity
4      4           opportunity    3           contact
```

Now, if I have the opportunity_id, I want to return all the contacts associated with that opportunity.

So if opportunity_id=4, the result of the successful query should be:

```
Hillary CLinton
Tiger Woods
```

But this is my query, which only returns 1 record:

```
SELECT
contacts.name
FROM
contacts
INNER JOIN relationships ON contacts.id = relationships.secondid
INNER JOIN opportunities ON opportunities.id = relationships.firstid
where
opportunities.id=4
and (relationships.firsttype='opportunity' and relationships.secondtype='contact')
or (relationships.firsttype='contact' and relationships.secondtype='opportunity')
```

I am stuck on how to do flip-flop the joins in this query.

EDIT:   I just discovered UNION and then tried this and it seems to work:

```
(select contacts.name from contacts where contacts.id =
    (select secondid as id from relationships  where (firstid = 4 and (firsttype='opportunity' and secondTtpe='contact' ) ) ) )
    UNION
 (select contacts.name from contacts where contacts.id =
    (select firstid as id from relationships where (secondid = 4 and (firsttype='contact' and secondtype='opportunity' ) ) ) )
```

But this seems clunky. Is this the best way to handle this?

Comment: I don't understand the realtionships. Perhaps if you'd used different sets of numbers for contacts and opportunities...

Comment: That relationships table is horrible. Why does it matter what the first type and second type are, they're always going to be contact and opportunity. Just have a contact_id and an opportunity_id.

Comment: @Andrew I know but it's not my table, it's in an open source CRM. And there are other relationship types, such as Accounts.

Comment: Please check @carito answer and tried it... it's the best way

Comment: Relationships should each get their own table... this is horrible and not scalable and horrible. It is the biggest of code smells and a sign that you need to drop it and use another CRM, post haste.

Comment: @Andrew Again, I agree on the "desirable" design (that's how SugarCRM does it). But this CRM needs to make me some money like yesterday, so I just need to get the best query for the existing schema- per the question asked ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT contacts.name FROM contacts
    inner join (
        SELECT * from relationships
        where 
            (firstid = 4 and (firsttype='opportunity' and secondtype='contact' ) )
            or 
            (secondid= 4 and (firsttype='contact' and secondtype='opportunity' ) ) 
    ) rel
    on contacts.id = rel.id;
```

Comment: Where is rel.id coming from?

Comment: Your inner SELECT returns all the relationships correctly. But your outer SELECT returns NULL as there is no correlation between rel.id and contacts.id.

Comment: @lilbiscuit `rel` is an alias for the whole inner select (is like a new table created from `relationships` but in the way you need)... please try it (I've already tried it)

Comment: @charles-rojas you are right rel is just an alias, the relationship comes from "on contact.id = rel.id, I tried it and works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

In a simple way, you need to change the design of your table `relationships`, I'll suggest:

**relationships**

```
id     id_contact     id_opportunity
-------------------------------------
1      1              1
2      3              3
3      4              4
4      3              4
```

So with the changes on `relationships`, your query can look like:

```
SELECT contacts.name 
FROM contacts
INNER JOIN relationships ON contacts.id = relationships.id_contact
INNER JOIN opportunities ON opportunities.id = relationships.id_opportunity
WHERE opportunities.id=4;
```

You must remember to normalize your tables (so the table `relationships` must have an identifier from the other tables, just **one** from each table... thats why is an identifier), and be more careful in the `many-to-many` tables.

Comment: Relationships is not my table...I can't change the design.